# Odd Vertices When Using The Knife Tool

Tags: mesh, knife-tool

When I use the knife tool on my mesh, any face connected to the cut becomes "*incorrect*". (I don't know the true term)

[image]

The underside of my mesh was smooth before I cut the mesh. Now, there are odd triangles that even appear in the render.

Comment: Important addition to your question will be screenshots of mesh in Edit mode and stack of modifiers (also [a blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) can be useful). Generally there's too much distortion which causes bad shading and artifacts on triangles, most likely topology in that part should be redone.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your post and add more information so that others can help you.

Comment: We will need before and after pictures of the model in edit mode in order to do more than speculate.

Comment: I'm guessing you created an n-gon in the process of cutting, and now the tris that the n-gon consists of are prevalent in the shading. Try to reshape your topology to quads. Other than that, without seeing the .blend I'm guessing in the dark.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the <kbd>J</kbd> "join" tool instead?

Here is a link to the Blender Reference Manual on Vertex tools

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html